# If $F$ is an algebraically closed field, then every maximal ideal of $F[x_1,...,x_n]$ is of the form $(x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ideals

I have problem to understand all the proof of the theorem :

> If $F$ is an algebraically closed field, then every maximal ideal of $F[x_1,...,x_n]$ is of the form $(x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$.

**Proof :** Let $\mathfrak m\subset F[x_1,...,x_n]=:R$ be a maximal ideal of $R$ and let $$\varphi: R\longrightarrow R/\mathfrak m=:k$$
the projection. Since $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, $k$ is a field. Since $\mathfrak m$ is a proper ideal, $1\notin \mathfrak m$, and thus $F\cap \mathfrak m=(0)$.

**Q1) $\mathfrak m$ is a proper ideal of $R$, not of $F$, so how can we have $F\cap \mathfrak m=(0)$ since $\mathfrak m$ is even not in $F$ ?**

In particular, $\varphi|_F$ is an injection. Let $\bar x_i$ the residue classes of $x_i$ in $k$. Then, using $\varphi|_F$, we have that $k$ is the extension of $k$ by elements $\bar x_1,...,\bar x_n$.

**Q2) I don't understand this fact. I agree that $\varphi|_F$ is a field homomorphism, but why (and what does it mean) that $k$ is the extension of $F$ by the elements $\bar x_1,...,\bar x_n$ ?**

Since $F$ is algebraically closed, if $\bar x_i$ is algebraic over $F$, then it's contained in $F$. By reordering the variable, we may assume the the first $j$ are not algebraic, that is $k=F[\bar x_1,...,\bar x_j]$ where $\bar x_i$ is tanscendental of $f$ for $i=1,...,j$.

If $j=0$, then $k=F$. Then, let $c_i$ the residue classes of $x_i$ in $k\cong F$. Then, $\mathfrak m=\ker \varphi\supset (x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$, and since $\mathfrak m$ is maximal, we get $m= (x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$.

**Q3) I don't understand why $m=\ker \varphi\supset (x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$.**

For the rest, it's fine for the moment.

Comment: There seems to be a typo (or mistake) in (2). I think it should say "...ww have that $\;k\;$ is an extension **of** $\;F\;$ by elements..."  Check this, please.

Comment: For Q1, if $\mathfrak{m}$ contained a nonzero element of $c \in F$, it would contain $1$ because we can multiply by $c^{-1}$.  If $\mathfrak{m}$ contains $1$, it is all of $R$.

Comment: In 1) some kind of abuse of notation is going on. $F$ is included in $F[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ in the obvious way.

Comment: For 2) informally speaking if we have $x^2 +3y^2$, applying "class" we get $[x^2 +3y^2]\equiv[x]^2 + 3[y]^2$. That's it.

Comment: For 3) $\phi(x_i-c_i) = \phi(x_i) - \phi(c_i)= c_i - c_i=0$ (I'm abusing of $k \simeq F$) thus $(x_i - c_i) \in \ker \phi= \frak m$.

Comment: Note that $k=F[\overline x_1, \dots, \overline x_n]$ being a filed impiles that it contains $1/\overline x_1$ thus it can be wrttien as $1/\overline x_1 = p(\overline x_1, \dots, \overline x_n)$ thus you get $\overline x_1$ is algebraic and thus contained in $F$. This implies $k \simeq F$.

Comment: Note that algebrically close is important! Think about $\mathbb R[X]/(x^2+1) \simeq \mathbb C$ wixh is a filed. Thus $(x^2+1)$ is maximal!

Comment: The case of uncountable $F$ (for instance $\mathbb C$) is here at page 17 http://www1.mat.uniroma1.it/people/ogrady/intro-alg-geom-2012.pdf

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: Why would it contain $c^{-1}$ ? $\mathfrak m$ is not an ideal of $F$ but of $F[x_1,...,x_n]$, no ? For exampl, if I take $\mathfrak n=(x,y)$ in $k[x,y]$, then $\mathfrak n$ is not an ideal of $k$...

Comment: Nobody is saying $\mathfrak{m}$ is an **an ideal** of $F$.  It is an ideal of $R$.  But $R$ contains $F$ (“constants” are polynomials), so $\mathfrak{m}$ could contain some elements of $F$.

Comment: And re "Why would it contain $c^{-1}$?" The multiplicative closure of an ideal is stronger than for a subgroup.  If $\mathfrak{a}$ is an ideal and $a \in \mathfrak{a}$, then $ra \in \mathfrak{a}$ **for all $r\in R$.**  So if a nonzero scalar $c\in F$ is in $\mathfrak{m}$, we don't need $c^{-1} \in \mathfrak{m}$ to conclude $1 = c^{-1} c \in \mathfrak{m}$.  Of course, once we know $1\in\mathfrak{m}$, we know $c^{-1}$, and everything else in $R$, is in $\mathfrak{m}$.

Answer (score -1):

we know that any ideal of the form $(x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)$ is maximal,
and $F \cong k$ .Let $b_i=x_i(mod m) \in k$ and $a_i=\varphi^{-1}(b_i)$ then $x_i-a_i \in ker\varphi=m $ so $(x_1-c_1,...,x_n-c_n)\subseteq ker\varphi$. and from kronecker theorem: we have that $k$ is extension of $F$. if $F\cap m \ne (0)$ then $m=F$ contradiction.